# Executing nested async functions at different stages

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, boolean, task

If I have:

```
server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.doStuff() = async binary =>
            {
                 ...
                 await Method1();
                 ...
                 await Method2();
            };
        }
```

and the task `doStuff()` is invoked very frequently (every 20ms), how do I properly execute `Method1()` on the **first** `doStuff()` call and then `Method2()` on all subsequent `doStuff()` calls? I have tried using a boolean and if statements such that:

```
server.Start(socket =>
        {
            socket.doStuff() = async binary =>
            {
                if(firstCall == true)
                {
                   await Method1();
                   firstCall = false;
                }

                else
                await Method2();
            };
        }
```

However, I was finding that this code was failing because `await Method1();` was apparently being called more than once. So it seemed like when the next `doStuff()` is invoked, `Method1()` had not yet been awaited from the first `doStuff()` as it was still executing and therefore, `firstCall` was still `true`, causing `Method1()` to be called again. Is it possible to accomplish this without heaps of booleans? How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

To clarify... `.doStuff()` is invoked everytime the websocket receives a binary message (which occurs every 20ms). I cannot control this, so, working within these bounds: I want to call `Method1()` only **ONCE** and I want it to be called on the very first message (the first time `.doStuff()` is invoked). Every single other time `.doStuff()` is invoked, I want `Method2()` to be called and **NOT** `Method1()`. I would also like to make sure that once `Method1()` has been called, it **completes** before `Method2()` is called. If I lose some binary data here, it is not an issue.

Comment: Are you awaiting `doStuff()`?

Comment: Is there are requirement to have one method and not two?

Comment: this makes no sense.  It sounds like you want to run all of the methods one after another.  Why not just put all the methods in a separate function that is run asynchronously and await that?  And why is Dostuff called repeatedly?

Comment: I am sorry, I had explained this incorrectly, doStuff() is an Action that is simply invoked whenever it receives binary data from a websocket connection.

Comment: Please include the code where `doStuff()` is called.

Comment: When should the switch from Method1() to Method2() be exactly done? When DoStuff() enters should it set firstCall before or after Method1() finishs? If after, what should happen when DoStuff() enters a second time before Method1() finishs? If before, is it a problem for Method2() to run in parallel or in worst-case before Method1()?

Comment: firstCall is set in an initial invoked method when the websocket is first created. I want method1() to be called only once the entire time. It should be called the first time doStuff() is invoked. it needs to be called completely before method2() is called. Every other time doStuff() is triggered, only method2() should be called

Comment: What should happen if DoStuff() is called while Method1() didn't finish?

Comment: It will be called, this is what’s supposed to happen, but if method1() isn’t called then method2() shouldn’t be called until method1() has completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var beforeFirst = true;

server.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.doStuff = async () =>
    {
        if (beforeFirst) {
            beforeFirst = false;
            await Method1();
            socket.doStuff = Method2;
        }
    };
}
```

- When doStuff() is called the first time, it runs `Method1()`.
- When doStuff() is called while `Method1()` it does nothing.
- When `Method1()` is finished it replaces `doStuff()` with `Method2()`.

The only bad thing is that the set and read of `beforeFirst` should maybe be done through some `Interlocked` method to avoid a race condition at this place.

Comment: Interesting, I am not very familiar with lambda expressions so this stuff is sort of new to me. Will Method2() still be awaited in your code?

Comment: I am getting the error `No overload for Method2() matches delegate 'Action'`

Comment: How about `socket.doStuff = () => Method2()`?

Comment: Brilliant, I had to slightly modify your code to accept a parameter and run async but it works with `socket.OnBinary = async (binaryData) => await Method2()`. Say after a certain amount of time, I wanted to restart this process, is there an easy way to go from `socket.OnBinary = async (binaryData) => await Method2()` back to `socket.doStuff = async () => {if (beforeFirst) {beforeFirst = false; await Method1(); socket.doStuff = Method2;} };`? I'd rather not have to include the entire original method when I reassign `socket.OnBinary()` as I have around 60 lines of code in the block.

Comment: I would like to be able to go in the "opposite direction" also so to speak

Comment: You have to put your lambda code into a named function (a normal method like `Method2()`. Then you can write something like `socket.doStuff = async binaryData => MyDoStuffImpl(socket);`.

Comment: If I create a new method to contain the lambda code, that means I am also including the `socket.OnBinary = async (binaryData) => await Method2()` line, but `socket` will no longer exist in this namespace?

Comment: `socket` is an outer parameter, used within the lambda. So you have to add it as a parameter to your function `private async Task MyDoStuffImpl(MySocket socket)`, just as any other parameter you use within the lambda which is declared outside of the lambda.

Comment: Perfect, I got it working now! I really appreciate the help.